# can I use eth0 interface to connect to two different networks

Tags: switch, ethernet

I'm using Ubuntu on PC. I have switch with 5 ports, and Rasberry.

how can I connect to raspberry via `eth0` using static network `(192.068.0.0/24)`
and in same time connect to internet using another network (DHCP) via same interface `eth0` using the switch?. can I create two network in the same interface `eth0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create sub-interfaces within Ubuntu, and/or simply put secondary addressing on the interface.

There's a pretty straightforward example here:

http://ithelpblog.com/os/linux/debian/ubuntu-debian/create-sub-interface-secondary-ip-address-ubuntu-debian/

I have my Raspberry Pis all configured with a sub-interface on a dedicated management VLAN ID with static IPs for configuring them, and then the main eth0 interface configured via DHCP for when they are moved around.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just as root type for example:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.10.110
ifconfig eth0:2 10.10.10.10
```

to make those chanages permanent just edit  */etc/network/interfaces*

Comment: Is the `:1` and `:2` parts of `eth0:1` what the other answer calls sub-interfaces? You can create one by naming & starting to use it?

Answer (score 0):

you can add how many ip addresses you want:

```
sudo ip address add 192.168.0.123/24 dev eth0
sudo ip address add 10.10.10.123/24 dev eth0
```

or simply shorten it up with:

```
sudo ip a a 192.168.0.123/24 dev eth0
sudo ip a a 10.10.10.123/24 dev eth0
```

to remove ip address from interface

```
sudo ip address del 192.168.0.123/24 dev eth0
sudo ip address del 10.10.10.123/24 dev eth0
```

or again shorten up:

```
sudo ip a d 192.168.0.123/24 dev eth0
sudo ip a d 10.10.10.123/24 dev eth0
```

but remember, if you want to use internet you have to add a default route:

```
sudo ip route add default via <your router ip>
```

and nameserver. You have to edit as root /etc/resolv.conf and put this line in it

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

8.8.8.8 is google's nameserver, you can use any other